# Visual Studio 2022 Dock windows issue: Missing side by side boxes in the guide diamond on my Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: visual-studio-2022

When I used to select and drag the tab of document window, a guide diamond appears (see first picture), a large square box with four smaller ones to that large box's four sides. This allows me to drag a document to one side of document window (side by side) or stack them vertically.

[image: Expected guide diamond]

Right now, what I get is this, three boxes stacked vertically (without the two boxes to the side). This no longer allows me to drag and stack a document side by side (only vertically).

[image: Current guide diamond]

I'm not sure what I did to cause this.

Answer (score 0):

Close all tabs should do the trick!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35509017)